# How to represent this symbol - the vertical line denoting derivative at a point?

Tags: support, mathjax

Below is Taylor series defined that I'm attempting to represent as MathJax : 
[image]

Closest I have is :

$\sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac {f^k(0)} {k!} x^k = f(0) + \frac {df} {dk}x_0+ \frac 1 {2!} 
\frac {{d^2}f} {d{x^2}}x_0^2
$

How to represent the long vertical line after each $\frac {df} {dx}$ that is before $x$ ?

Comment: Try {a\over b}\Big| $${a\over b}\Big|$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson "{a\over b}\Big|_{0}" $${a\over b}\Big |_{0}$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both
$$f(0) + \left.\frac {df}{dx}\right|_0 x+ \frac 1{2!} \left. \frac {{d^2}f} {d{x^2}}\right|_0x^2 + \dots$$
and 
$$f(0) + \left.\frac {df}{dx}\right\rvert_0 x+ \frac 1{2!} \left. \frac {{d^2}f} {d{x^2}}\right\rvert_0x^2 + \dots$$
seem to me like reasonable approximation.

Obtained by
`$$f(0) + \left.\frac {df}{dx}\right|_0 x+ \frac 1{2!} \left. \frac {{d^2}f} {d{x^2}}\right|_0x^2 + \dots$$`
and
`$$f(0) + \left.\frac {df}{dx}\right\rvert_0 x+ \frac 1{2!} \left. \frac {{d^2}f} {d{x^2}}\right\rvert_0x^2 + \dots$$`.
I simply copied part of your text and added `\left.` and `\right|` or `\right\rvert`.

TeX and MathJax are not the same thing, but you might probably find some reasonable advise on TeX.SE: [Math symbol question: Vertical bar for ''evaluated at …''](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40160)